# Calculate average number of days between two dates for unique fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need some help with a single formula in finding unique tasks and then getting the average between two dates.  Looking at the below example:

---

Task        Closed        Created
Task1  3/13/2018     1/1/2018
Task1  3/13/2018     1/1/2018
Task1  3/13/2018     1/1/2018
Task2  3/13/2018     2/1/2018
Task2  3/13/2018     2/1/2018
Task3  3/13/2018     3/1/2018

---

I need to take Task1 and subtract 3/13/2018 from 1/1/2018 to get 71
I need to take Task2 and subtract 3/13/2018 from 2/1/2018 to get 40
I need to take Task3 and subtract 3/13/2018 from 3/1/2018 to get 12
This gives me an average answer of 41

---

Is there a formula I can use to get this answer of 41?  
I tried {=AVERAGE(B2:B6 - C2:C7)}, but I don't know how to have it first check if unique.  Something like {=If A2:A7 is Unique, AVERAGE(B2:B6 - C2:C7)}

To complicate things further, there are times when there will be no values in column B (Closed)

Comment: (1) So, are you saying that, if there are multiple rows for a task, they will be identical?  Will they always be together? (2) What do you mean “there are times when there will be no values in column B”?  Do you mean that some tasks will have no “Closed” date?  (If so, how do you want them handled?  Do you want those tasks to be ignored?)  Or do you mean that some ***rows*** for a task will have no “Closed” date? (If so, you really need to explain more.) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula in an adjacent column to count the occurrences of each task:

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)`

You need to put this into the first row and drag-to-fill it down the column. This causes it to transpose correctly to produce the desired result. The formula counts how many rows up to the current row contain the same value:

```
Task1   1
Task1   2   
Task2   1
Task3   1
Task1   3   
Task4   1
Task2   2   
Task3   2
```

Then, use another formula in a new column to capture the date difference but only when the occurrence count equals 1:

`=IF(D1=1,B1-C1,"")`

```
Task1   1/01/2011   1/01/2010   1   365
Task1   1/01/2011   1/01/2010   2   
Task2   4/01/2011   1/04/2010   1   278
Task3   6/01/2011   1/06/2010   1   219
Task1   1/01/2011   1/01/2010   3   
Task4   10/01/2011  1/10/2010   1   101
Task2   4/01/2011   1/04/2010   2   
Task3   6/01/2011   1/06/2010   2
```

Then average the last column.

You can of course combine the two formulae above - I simply provided both for explanation's sake.

Note that the dates don't affect the occurrence count - only the first occurrence will have the date calculation (so this assumes you don't allow different date ranges for different rows otherwise this can't work - your example shows duplicate date ranges).

You need to decide what you want to do with your empty column B. For example you can ignore non-closed tasks in the date difference formula as follows:

`=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B4)),D4=1),B4-C4,"")`